# Kony FFI integration issues

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, ffi, temenos-quantum

Recently i am facing an issue while integrating amazon sdk using FFI

The Issue:

cannot find symbol

symbol  : method getOrCreateInstance(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

The Link to the amazon class reference

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/

i am defining above method's parameters as:

context as java.lang.Object

appId as java.lang.String

poolId as java.lang.String

or there is an alternative to integrate third party libraries into Kony

Answer (score 0):

The missing method is [MobileAnalyticsManager.getOrCreateInstance(Context, String, String)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/amazonmobileanalytics/MobileAnalyticsManager.html#getOrCreateInstance(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). It belongs to Amazon Mobile Analytics library aws-android-sdk-mobileanalytics. It was added in version 2.2.4 released on 7/22/2015. Make sure you have the jar in your class path. For further information, check out [AWS SDK for Android developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/).

Comment: I am not familiar with Kony. From what I see, this is more like a general question for Kony. Probably you need to provide more context, like Kony version, SDK version, failure message, stacktrace etc for others to help you.

Comment: Anyways thanks ,
i figured out a way by creating new java project implementing native code there and importing the jar to project